# Rspec for model method which are dependent form each other and uses gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

During my RSpec journey I want to test 3 methods from my user model, each method is dependent on each other. They are some kind of helpers method for gem stock_qoute and just checking whether the search item (stock) has been already added to the portfolio or whether the user has already reached the limit of added items (10 stocks). Those methods are used in view.

I was trying to mock this gem but I think this is not the simplest way to do so. I think I can skip the whole gem and use only variable but I have no idea how to do so. I'm using devise and Rspec without FactoryBot.

user.rb

```
has_many :user_stocks
has_many :stocks, through: :user_stocks

def stock_already_added?(ticker_symbol)
 stock = Stock.find_by_ticker(ticker_symbol)
 return false unless stock

 user_stocks.where(stock_id: stock.id).exists?
end

def under_stock_limit?
 (user_stocks.count < 10)
end

def can_add_stock?(ticker_symbol)
 under_stock_limit? && !stock_already_added?(ticker_symbol)
end
```

find_by_ticker method from different model:

```
def self.find_by_ticker(ticker_symbol)
 where(ticker: ticker_symbol).first
end
```

view file:

```
  <% if current_user.can_add_stock?(@stock.ticker) %>
      <%= link_to 'Add stocks', user_stocks_path(user: current_user, stock_ticker: @stock.ticker),
                                              class: 'btn btn-xs btn-success', method: :post %>
    <% else %>
      <span class="label label-default">
        Stock cannot be added because you have added
        <% if !current_user.under_stock_limit? %>
        10 stocks
        <% end %>
        <% if current_user.stock_already_added?(@stock.ticker) %>
          this stock
          <%= link_to 'Remove', user_stock_path, method: :delete %>
        <% end %>
      </span>
    <% end %>
```

user_spec.rb:

```
  describe 'Add stock' do
    user = User.create(email: 'test@example.com', password: 'password')

    context 'when user add the same stock' do
      let(:stock) { Stock.new(name: 'Goldman Sachs', ticker: 'GS', last_price: 112.4) }

      it "return false" do
        user_stocks = UserStock.new(user: user, stock: stock)
        expect(user_stocks.can_add_stock?('GS')).to eq false
      end
    end
  end
```

Right now I've got an error:

> 1) User Add stock when user add the same stock return false
>        Failure/Error: expect(user_stocks.can_add_stock?('GS')).to eq true
>
> ```
> NoMethodError:
>   undefined method `can_add_stock?' for #<UserStock:0x00007fb0efa4d3a8>
> # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:29:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
> ```

Comment: Which line generates the error? Could you please add it's full stacktrace?

Comment: Post updated. Line 29 is corresponding with ```expect(user_stocks.can_add_stock?('GS')).to eq true```

Comment: Looking at you spec error it looks like you are calling the `can_add_stock?` method on the `user_stocks` object but that method is defined in `user` model not `user_stock` model hence you are getting the error `undefined method can_add_stock? for #<UserStock>`

Comment: ```can_add_stock``` is defined in ```user``` model, like I wrote above and it's called in views under partial ```user/_result```. Other methods are also in ```user``` model so I don't understand why ```user_stocks``` object would be used

Comment: But in line 29, which causes the error, you're calling `user_stocks.can_add_stock?('GS')`, why you're surprised? Looks like we need the whole code of your test

Comment: Thank you @Vasilisa you are right. I forgot also to add specs code, sorry for that - updated.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call `can_add_stock?` on user_stock, when it is method of the User model? You need to check stocks for user

```
describe 'Add stock' do
  let(:user) { User.create(email: 'test@example.com', password: 'password') }

  context 'when user add the same stock' do
    let(:stock) { Stock.create(name: 'Goldman Sachs', ticker: 'GS', last_price: 112.4) }

    it "return false" do
      user.stocks << stock
      expect(user.can_add_stock?('GS')).to eq false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Ok but if I have line which create stock (as above under context - ```let(:stock) { Stock.create(name: 'Goldman Sachs', ticker: 'GS', last_price: 112.4) }``` ) it should means that I cannot add stock with ticker 'GS' so I should get false (as in your line -expect to eq false). Unfortunately I've got true instead of false.

Comment: Not sure, why it happened, try to debug it yourself